# What's the omission/error out here?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

There should be an error/omission in the next code but I can't see where mostly because I've never used threads. Can someone please find what I'm missing?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JavaSwingTest extends JDialog {
    private JLabel m_countLabel;

    private Timer m_timer = new Timer();

    private class IncrementCountTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_countLabel.setText(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() 
/ 1000));
        }
    }

    private JavaSwingTest() {
        createUI();

        m_timer.schedule(new IncrementCountTask(), 1000, 1000);
    }

    private void createUI() {
        Button button1 = new Button("Action1");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                doLongOperation();
            }

        });
        add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        m_countLabel = new JLabel(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis() 
/ 1000));
        add(m_countLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    /**
     * Simulates an operation that takes time to complete.
     */
    private void doLongOperation() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ignored for this test
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaSwingTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The omission/error is that you omitted the part of your question where you tell us what the error you're trying to fix is.

Comment: Hm. You are setting the value of a Swing component from a thread, which is not the main thread (timer).

Comment: @Dirk:  `setText` is one of very few Swing methods that are threadsafe.

Comment: Oops my mistake Dirk, it's a JLabel not a text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing, like most UI toolkits, is not thread-safe. Your setText() call should be forwarded to the event thread.

To initiate GUI work from the timer thread, use [SwingUtilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html).invokeLater() or invokeAndWait().

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, `setText()` should be called from the Swing Event Dispatch Thread since it is not threadsafe.  The simplest way for you to fix this is to use [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) (which calls the action already on the EDT), not `java.util.Timer`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`SwingWorker`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) would allow your `doLongOperation()` to execute without blocking the EDT, while also offering a convenient way to periodically update the GUI. Theres a complete example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/randomdata).